# Grunt grunt-contrib-jasmine report output to a log file

Tags: logging, npm, gruntjs, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I am using this lib to create my jasmine test https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine
I have the test framework running without problem but when it print out things in console, it contains too much junk info that I do not want, is there anyway to output the test result into a log file?

In my gruntfile.js,  I have

```
grunt.registerTask('test', ['jasmine']);
```

Is there anyway when we run `grunt test` , it output all result into log.txt  something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use task specific logs with [logfile-grunt](https://github.com/brutaldev/logfile-grunt) to capture all output from jasmine:

https://github.com/brutaldev/logfile-grunt

Or just pipe the output directly to a file:

```
grunt test > log.txt
```

Or if you'd just like to reduce the output from jasmine you can use the display:short option

```
jasmine : {
    //your config
    options : {
        display : 'short'
    }
}
```